# MongoDB river VS RabbitMQ river VS Background job (resque)

Tags: solr, indexing, elasticsearch, resque

I want to switch my Rails project from Solr to Elastic Search (just for fun), but I'm not sure about the best approach to index the documents. Right now I'm using Resque (background job) for this task, but I've been digging about "rivers" on Elastic Search and they look promising.

Anyone who has experience on this topic can bring me some tips? performance results? scalability?

Thanks in advance

P.S: Although is just for fun at the moment, I have in mind to migrate from Solr to Elastic Search a larger project in production.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand your situation/concerns from your question. With elasticsearch, you either push data in, or use a river to pull them.

When you are pushing the data in, you're in control of how your feeder operates, how it processes documents, how the whole pipeline looks (gather data > language analysis > etc > index). Using a river may be a convenient way how to quickly pull some data into elasticsearch from a certain source (CouchDB, RDBMS), or to continuously pull data eg. from a RabbitMQ stream.

Since you're considering elasticsearch in a context of a Rails project, you'll probably try out the[Tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire) gem at some point. Supposing you're using an ActiveModel-compatible ORM (for SQL or NoSQL databases), importing is as easy as:

```
$ rake environment tire:import CLASS=MyClass
```

See the [Tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire) documentation and the [relevant Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Karmi. A few more questions: How does Tire internally sync the Rails database (in my case MongoDB) with the Elastic Search index? What would happen if the index task fails (i.e. Elastic Search is down)? And just for checking, I guess that once you define the mappings, it only updates Elastic Search index is one of the parameters of the mapping has changed, right? Thanks in advance, and sorry for these newbie questions

Comment: That's a lot of questions for one comment... (err.. update below :)

Comment: 1. You choose how you wanna sync -- Tire provides a callback module which sync on model updates/deletes. You may wanna use other strategy, written by yourself.

2. Nothing happens by default when the indexing fails -- that's a different game where you set the rules.

3. Tire will update the ES index based on a) your mappings, b) your `to_indexed_json` method